# How to send value from one form to another form

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public string str;
private DataGridViewCell ActiveCell = null;

private void CopyClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ActiveCell != null && ActiveCell.Value != null)

    str = authLeaveView.Rows[ActiveCell.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    Clipboard.SetText(str);
    recLeavePop rlp = new recLeavePop();
    rlp.Show();
}
```

This is my code and it work perfectly. Now my question is: if I want to send `the value of "str"` to another form, how should I achieve it?

Comment: Show code of other form as well. Other form already exists or you have to make a new instance of it? You could pass value using other form's object.

Comment: This question has been asked many times on SO. Did you check the related questions before asking?

Comment: @HassanNisar..i want to make new instance on other form and show that value on to message box

Comment: @DanielKelley..yes i have checked but i didnt get proper answer that why i have ask here...

Comment: @jayrathod: What exactly do you mean by "sending a value to a form"? Should the value be stored in a field or property of that other form, or be displayed in a particular control? Perhaps explain what will/should happen with `str` once it "arrives at" the other form.

Comment: see suppose this is from1 and it have value of str=123 ; now on recLeavePop form i want this value of str which is 123... understood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your `str` as a public **Property** with a private setter.

```
public string Str { get; private set; }

private DataGridViewCell ActiveCell = null;

private void CopyClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ActiveCell != null && ActiveCell.Value != null)

    Str = authLeaveView.Rows[ActiveCell.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    Clipboard.SetText(Str);
    recLeavePop rlp = new recLeavePop();
    rlp.Show();
}
```

In the other form, call `YourFormNameWithStrProperty.Str` to use the value.

**Edit**

I saw this piece of code in your comments:

> In the other form, I used `Form1 form = new Form1()` but then the `str` gives null.

This is an obvious behavior. Like what I said in my comment, you get null because you query the value before it gets set. When a new instance just gets constructed, everything is new and undefined, include your **Str** property.

If you want every of your new `Form1` object somehow takes care of the `Str` value from other `Form1` instances, I suggest you do this:

Change your constructor of `Form1` to private and create a function to return the instance. In the function, pre-set the `Str` value to the new instance if we've already have one:

```
private Form1()
{
    // do your construction here
    Initialize();
}

private Form1(string strValue)
{
    // do default construction first
    Initialize();
    // set the Str value
    Str = strValue;
}

public static Form1 GetInstance()
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(Str) ?  new Form1() : new Form1(Str);
}
```

Then in your "the other form", call `Form1.GetInstance()` to construct the object.

**Edit 2**

Whatever, the previous method got some constraints and seems to be irrelavent to your problem. Try the following method:

Instead of creating public property in Form1, create a public property in "the other form" which needs the value. That is, in your **Form1**:

```
private void CopyClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ActiveCell != null && ActiveCell.Value != null)

    // by the way is this rlp your "The other form"?
    recLeavePop rlp = new recLeavePop();

    TheOtherForm.Str = authLeaveView.Rows[ActiveCell.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    Clipboard.SetText(TheOtherForm.Str);
    rlp.Show();
}
```

Comment: still it gives null value on other form

Comment: can you show your implementation of the other form? `Null` means the value hasn't been set, which indicates you query the value earlier than it has been set.

Comment: according to your code this value is set but now i want that value on  recLeavePop form....how can i get that value on  recLeavePop form?

Comment: on my other form i have writtem form1 frm = new form1() ;  MessageBox.Show(frm.str); but it display null value..

Comment: I've edited the answer, please have a look :)

Comment: no...still it gives null value.

Comment: @jayrathod I couldn't understand it. I think you'd better post the entire code of your Form1 and the other Form so that we could understand what you really need.

Comment: I edited again, please check :)

Comment: recLeavePop yes this is other form i want to send value to that form ... you can consider form1 = recLeavePop form

Answer (score 2):

The concept of appwide variables is the same as in classes.

I've got a form called form 1 -

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblText.Text = Form2.testVariable;
        }
    }
}
```

Now look at the FORM I'm receiving the variable from. Exagtly as it works in the dotnetfiddle I linked to you -  dotnetfiddle.net/YfKNX9

Form 2

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public static string testVariable = "potato";

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

It can't be made any more clearer I'm afraid.

Comment: static variables? but what if you wanted to have two instances of Form2 in your application?

Comment: Good question. Without testing it, it can be assumed that it most likely won't work unless there is a function available to differentiate between the 2 instances. Therefore in that case this method probably isn't the way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

**Use static keyword for str variable**

```
public static string str;
```

Assign the value in one form and use the same variable in second form.

**EDIT:-**

Create a new class with MyClass and create a static variable inside it.

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static string str;
}
```

Assign the value is form1 as

```
MyClass.str="Some Value";
```

And use it in the other form as

```
MyClass.str
```

Comment: no it gives error - 0cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: try using `Form1.str`, considering Form1 is name of the form.

Comment: Have you tried to put a breakpoint in your CopyClick method to see if there even is a value there before you are getting a null value returned?

Comment: Console.Write("The value of str in this CopyClick method " + str); // Place this at the end of the method and ensure that your str has a value. Declaring the string str as static should be enough for other forms/classes to have access to the variable.

Comment: but how can i use MyClass.str in other form ???

Comment: on other form i have wriiten - from1 frm = new form1(); frm.MyClass.str ; then it gives error in MyClass.str

Comment: You have to understand what's going on, I've made a dotnetfiddle for you to see. https://dotnetfiddle.net/YfKNX9

Comment: using a static field for passing data is bad design

Answer (score 1):

You could make a second constructor for the form that accepts a string parameter and saves it in an internal variable

```
private string Str {get;set;}

public void recLeavePop(string str)
{
    Str = str;
}
```

or declare a global static property and set it before declaring the form

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static string Str {get;set;}
}
```

and in your code

```
MyClass.Str = str;
recLeavePop rlp = new recLeavePop();
rlp.Show();
```

then accessing it inside the form with

```
MyClass.Str;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass another form data then add a "SetData" method and call that from the other form passing in the data.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form1Data _data;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public SetData(Form1Data data)
    {
        _data = data;
    }
}

struct MyData
{
    public string Name;
    public string Address;
}
```

I would avoid passing the data in the constructor only because you might want to set the data after construction, and also the form designer can get a bit crazy if you mess with the constructor iirc.